# VBA: Convert String to Range

Tags: range

When a mid-result that represent a range of numbers "2219; 2220; 2221; 2222; 2223"...etc is stored in a specific cell my macro works well. But if I assign this same range of numbers to a variable (in my case named "Final") instead of the cell, and try to assign it to a range, it returns run-time error in a code 424 Object required. The rest of the code sort numbers (separated with ";") and then decrease the number by last digit and delete the 9 following numbers if those 10 numbers are consecutive while fist ends with 0 and last ends with 9. So if the range of numbers are "2219; 2220; 2221; 2222; 2223; 2224; 2225; 2226; 2227; 2228; 2229; 2230; 2231" the result shall be "2219; 222; 2230; 2231"

```
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Final, Fkod As String
 
'This works:
Cells(Count + 2, 5) = Right(Fkod, Len(Fkod) - 2)
Set WorkRng = Cells(Count + 2, 5)
 
'If I want to avoid showing midresult in a Cells(Count + 2, 5) by introducing variable "Final", it returns run-time error with "code 424 Object required" in a last row below:

Final = Right(Fkod, Len(Fkod) - 2)
'content of Final is "2219; 2220; 2221; 2222; 2223" 
Set WorkRng = Range(Final)
'also tried with same result
'Set WorkRng = Final
```

' the rest of the code looks as follows:

```
Set objArrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    Arr = VBA.Split(Rng.Value, "; ")
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
        xMin = i
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(Arr)
            If Arr(xMin) > Arr(j) Then
                xMin = j
            End If
        Next j
    If xMin <> i Then
        temp = Arr(i)
        Arr(i) = Arr(xMin)
        Arr(xMin) = temp
    End If
    Next i

    For j = 1 To duzina
    For x = 0 To UBound(Arr)
          
    If x + 9 > UBound(Arr) Then
        Exit For
    End If
    
    If Right(Arr(x), 1) = 0 And (Left(Arr(x), Len(Arr(x)) - 1) = Left(Arr(x + 9), Len(Arr(x + 9)) - 1)) Then
        Arr(x) = Left(Arr(x + 9), Len(Arr(x + 9)) - 1)
        For p = 1 To 9
            For r = x + 1 To UBound(Arr) - 1
                Arr(r) = Arr(r + 1)
            Next r
            ReDim Preserve Arr(LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr) - 1)

        Next p
            Rng.Value = VBA.Join(Arr, "; ")
    End If

    Next x
    Next j

Next
```

Comment: The [Excel Range object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) `Represents a cell, a row, a column, a selection of cells containing one or more contiguous blocks of cells, or a 3D range`. Your data string "2219; 2220; 2221; 2222; 2223" does not contain cell coordinates, they are just *numbers*, and the Range object is unable to deal with that (not meant to + not able to). Please give a better explanation of what you want to use those numbers for.

Comment: It seems to me you should just send the value of `Final` into that splitting and checking algorithm. The code processes a *string*, and `Final` contains that *string*. Range has nothing to do with all this, Range is for **Worksheet Cell handling** and has no use here.